# What is the best way to write a data loader?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 2.5 and the Hibernate that goes with it. I'm running against an Oracle 11g database.

I have created my DAOs which extend HibernateTemplate. Now I want to write a loader that inserts 5 million rows in my person table. I have written this in a simple minded fashion like read a row from a CSV file, turn it into a person, save into the table. Keep doing this until CSV file is empty.

The problem is that I run out of heap space at about 450000 rows. So I double the size of memory from 1024m to 2048m and now I run out of memory after about 900000 rows.

Hmmmmm....

So I've read some things about turning off the query cache for Hibernate, but I'm not using a L2 cache, so I don't think this is the issue.

I've read some things about JDBC2 batching, but I don't think that applies to hibernate.

So, I'm wondering if maybe there's a fundamental thing about Hibernate that I'm missing.

Comment: Is this literally just a matter of reading from the csv and loading into the table or are you doing some other processing? If it's the former and this is a one-off static data load I would recommend using a bulk loader (such as Oracle sqlldr).

Comment: @DaveRlz Other than there's two tables being loaded, I'm not doing any other processing. But I want my solution to be database independent.

Comment: If only the documentation had... wait, it's there: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-statelesssession

Comment: @JBNizet the problems with this are: 1) I'm using the Spring templates and don't have direct access to the ssesion, 2) The transactions are getting flushed/committed just fine b/c I can look at the table I'm loading and see the rows going in. The problem is external to the transaction.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this?

Comment: DaveRlz is right, use a bulk loader. Oracle's sql loader is orders of magnitude faster than anything you can do with jdbc or Hibernate. If you are really determined you might try Spring-Batch, you can set a chunk size to control how many rows go in per transaction.

Comment: @TheThom If they didn't explain already they're gone already and can't answer you.

Comment: @TheThom That said, I'd say it's because of the "what is the best", and that your question is written as if it asks more for an open-ended design discussion rather than how to resolve a problem. (For one, you haven't outlined the code you're using, as in what goes on where.)

Comment: @TheThom Like, say, my guess at what the fundamental thing you're missing about Hibernate that Hibernate **always** caches everything you load in the lifetime of a `Session`, and this is orthogonal to transactions. (Amongst other fundamental things, like that the L2 cache and the query cache are not the same thing.) But it's hard to say this with any certainty since you haven't given us any information as to what's kept in the Session or not.

Comment: To put this another way, your problem isn't that you don't have "the best" way of writing a *data loader* (which is a vague term and thus has no place in a question title), it's that you don't even have a *good enough* way of writing it on accounts of your batching / chunking code being plain incorrect. And this (i.e. what your actual question should be) is buried all the way in paragraph 3 of your post. The unfortunate consequence is that someone skimmed the title and paragraphs 1 and 2 and made his mind up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I wouldn't be using hibernate for that. ORMs are not designed to load million of rows into DBs. Not saying that you can't, but it's a bit like digging a swimming pool with a electric drill; you'd use an excavator for that, not a drill.

In your case, I'd load the CSV directly to the DB with a loader application that comes with databases. If you don't want to do that, yes, batch inserts will be way more efficient. I don't think Hibernate let's you do that easily though. If I were you I'd just use plain JDBC, or at most Spring JDBC.

If you have complicated businesslogic in the entities and absolutely have to use Hibernate, you could flush every N records as Richard suggests. However, I'd consider that a pretty bad hack.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with EclipseLink, holding a single transaction open while inserting/updating *many* records results in the symptoms you've experienced.

You are working with an `EntityManager` (of some sort, JPA or Hybernate specific - it's still managing `Entity`s).  It's trying to keep the working set in memory, for the life of the transaction.

A general solution was to commit & the restart the transaction after every N inserts; a typical N for me was 1000.

---

As a footnote, with some version (undefined, it's been a few years) of EclipseLink, a session flush/clear didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running out of space due to your first-level cache (the Hibernate session). You can flush the Hibernate session periodically to keep memory usage down, and break up the work into chunks by committing every few thousand rows, keeping the database's transaction log from getting too big.

But using Hibernate for a load task like that will be slow, because JDBC is slow. If you have a good idea what the environment will be like, you have a cap on the amount of data, and you have a big enough window for processing, then you can manage, but in a situation where you want it to work in multiple different client sites and you want to minimize the time spent on figuring out problems due to some client site's load job not working, then you should go with the database's bulk-copy tool.

The bulk-copy approach means the database suspends all constraint checking and index-building and transaction logging, instead it concentrates on slurping the data in as fast as possible. Because JDBC doesn't get anything like this level of cooperation from the database it can't compete. At a previous job we replaced a JDBC loader task that took over 8 hours to run with a SQLLoader task that took 20 minutes.

You do sacrifice database independence, but all databases have a bulk-copy tool (because DBAs rely on them) so you will have a very similar process for each database, only the exe you invoke and the way the file formatting is specified should change. And this way you make the best use of your processing window.